# Returning single value for all grep matches through directory

Tags: unix, terminal, grep

I'm using Grep to go through every file in a directory and match a word. It will return the match count for each file, but I was wondering if there was a way to return the total of all the matches in one return?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if grep can do it, but it's easy to do with awk:

`grep -c foo * | awk -F: '{sum += $2} END {print sum}'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wc`: `grep "regexp" * | wc -l`

Answer (score 0):

how about

cat * | grep -c *regexp*

You'll probably get '*xxx* is a directory' and similar warnings to stderr unless you use some flag to suppress them, but the count seems to work.